# How to connect Ruby Cygwin environment to with a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, cygwin

I run a Windows XP machine, and use Cygwin to run my ruby environment.  I usually connect to a MySQL database, but for purposes of testing the application when using a SQL Server database I need to setup a connection to my SQL Server database.  Does anyone know how to setup my environment to connect to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the activerecord-sqlserver-Adapter on GitHub